# Which prototype is used for creating a node with an unknown tag

Tags: javascript, prototype, nodes, custom-element

I want to know when i create an unknown HTMLElement like an apple-tag:

```
var apple = document.create("apple")
```

i would be interested out of which prototype it's made of...
because i tried:

```
apple.isPrototypeOf(HTMLElement.prototype)
console: false
```

My question is what prototype is used for unknown tags.

Thank you!

Comment: `Object` prototype ?

Comment: only the object prototype??

Comment: You've got it the wrong way round, you should test `HTMLElement.prototype.isPrototypeOf(apple)`. Or `apple instanceof HTMLElement` (which tests the entire prototype chain). Or just do `console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(apple))`

Comment: Why are you creating unknown element types in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is [`HTMLUnknownElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement). It is a subclass of `HTMLElement`.

```js
var myApple = document.createElement('apple');
document.write(myApple.constructor.name); // "HTMLUnknownElement"
```

Comment: exactly 'HTMLUnknownElement.prototype'